tests working in springboot 2.7(mockito 4.x) not working in spring boot 3.4.0 or 3.1.4 (mockito 5.x)
tests working in mockito 4.x are not working with mockito 5.x getting error after migrating spring from 2.7 to 3.1.4.
Error:
Suppressed: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here
@activeprofiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(SampleApiController.class)
@slf4j
@import({MetricsAutoConfiguration.class, CompositeMeterRegistryAutoConfiguration.class})
public class GetFailedTest {

@MockBean
MockClass Mockobj;

JsonFileReader reader = new JsonFileReader();

@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

@BeforeAll
static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
System.setProperty("junit", "true");
}

@test
void testSampleFail() throws Exception {
log.info("testSampleFail");
String url = "xxxxx";
when(Mockobj.getMethod(anyString(), org.mockito.Mockito.any(StringBuilder.class)))
.then(new Answer() {
 @OverRide
 public Integer answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
 StringBuilder sbd = invocation.getArgument(1);
 sbd.append(reader.getJsonStringFromFile(Constants.sample));
 throw new RuntimeException("Runtime exception");
 }
 });
 MvcResult result =
 this.mockMvc.perform(get(url)).andExpect(status().is5xxServerError()).andReturn();
 log.info(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
 }
 }
 


I tried
@Mock(mockMaker = MockMakers.SUBCLASS)
instead of @MockBean
I was getting jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed:

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have updated the sample code , this was working with spring boot 2.7 but not working with Spring 3.4.0 . I tried  changing the syntax from when . then  answer to doanswer.when  this doesn't seems to be working

Which line contains the error? "Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here" <- where is "here"?

it is at when condition
